# Django: Checking source code of automatically generated functions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Remember how you can use manage.py to check the source SQL of the tables generated by manage.py syncdb and Django's ORM?

Is there any way to have a similar function, but to see the source code of automatically generated functions? For example the save() and clean() functions of a certain form.

Having access to such source code would give me great flexibility in modifying these functions, which is something we sometimes need.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L74 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope — Djagno doesn't generate any Python functions.

To see the source for Django's functions, though, you can check the source (ex, https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L74 , as @mipadi suggested).

You can find the file that contains the implementation for any given class like this:

```
>>> from django.forms import forms
>>> forms.__file__
'…/django/forms/forms.pyc'
```